# C++ Send e-mail at exit

Tags: c++, email, send, atexit

What I'm trying to do is send an e-mail when exiting my program.
I use `atexit();` function to do this but... it's not working properly.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

void SendEmail()
{
    //lot of code here
}

void Print()
{
    std::cout << "Bye!";
    system("pause");
}

void Terminate()
{
    SendEmail(blahblah); // Doesn't work
    Print(); // Works
}

int main()
{
    atexit(Terminate);

    while (true) Sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Does `SendEmail();` function take too much time and doesn't do anything? It doesn't even print the server responses (it works fine when used in `main();`)

Comment: Well, for one the `SendEmail()` function in your example doesn't take a `blahblah` parameter, which is not even defined in your example. And then I'd daresay the problem is somewhere in `//lot of code here`... have you tried your *real* `SendEmail()` from within `main()` successfully before?

Comment: registered `atexit` handlers only run during a normal exit, not if the process is killed... and you leave no mechanism for normal exit.

Comment: Welcome to programming, where your first step with any problem is to break the problem down to smaller manageable tasks. For example, in this case, do you even know if `SendEmail()` works when you change it to not be part of `atexit()`? If you don't know this, you should before you ask for help.

Comment: How are you exiting your program?  CTRL+C?  `kill -KILL pid` ?  `TerminateProcess()` ?  crashing?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....) then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`), in particular by setting a breakpoint on your `SendEmail` function

Comment: Minus 4 is very harsh. This is not the meta site!

Comment: Make certain of two things: 1) you are using `std::atexit`, not `atexit` and 2) that  everything you still need alive to execute `SendEmail` is still alive by the time it is called.

Comment: @P45Imminent Harsh, yes, but the question cannot be answered in it's current state without the use of a crystal ball, a Flux Capacitor, or a few grams of Unobtainium. Best we can do is give suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

You don't know that other resources have been shut down prior to the running of `atexit`. These might have been important for the successful running of `SendMail`.

Comment: The OS doesn't get involved until _after_ `atexit`.

Comment: I'm confident the OS is inextricably linked with the running of any program on linux or Windows. But I think I know what you're trying to say. I've edited.

Comment: Actually, the OS is mostly not involved, as that would be too slow. Switching from program to OS and back is an expensive context switch.